# Posting array of input using AngularJs

Tags: php, html, angularjs, forms, http-post

hope you fine and well

i have the following form in html

```
<div class="table-responsive " >
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr ng-repeat="x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
<td>
<td align="center">Price: <input name="price[]" type="number"  ng-model="info.price[x]"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and im submitting data to the insert function using this:

```
ng-submit="addPrice(info)
```

here is my function:

```
$scope.addPrice= function(info){
info.price= [];
$http.post('../files/insert.php',{"price":info.price}).success(function(data){
if (data == true) {
}
});
}
```

in the php file:

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     
    $price[]=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->price);    
    $query = "INSERT into myTbl (price) VALUES ('$price[0]')";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

as you see i'm trying to insert the first price input , but whatever i enter in the input it insert 0 in the database!

where is the problem ?! or what i'm doing wrong?

regards

Comment: Why are you re-initializing `info.price = []` before posting it ?? And how you are expecting some value should be there in that array ?

Comment: even without initialization, it still insert 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove `info.price` initialization from the following part,

```
$scope.addPrice= function(info){
    //info.price= [];
    $http.post('../files/insert.php',{"price":info.price}).success(function(data){
       if (data == true) {
       }
    });
}
```

Now,

```
$scope.addPrice= function(info){
    console.log(info.price); /* This will now show an array of values, 
                             that is value from each input within the ng-repeat*/
    $http.post('../files/insert.php',{"price":info.price}).success(function(data){
       if (data == true) {
       }
    });
}
```

In the server side, you will get an array of values in `$data->price`.

Comment: Do $data->price getting value passed from the client side? Check $data->price value in the server side

Comment: this what im using in the php file 
$price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->price);
$query = "INSERT into myTbl (price) VALUES ('$price[0]')";

i fill all the element of price in the form ! but it insert 0 in the database.

Comment: you can echo $data->price in the server side and check whether it contains the value passed from client side

Comment: im submitting also other inputs , they work fine but they are single values not arrays,, i really dont know where is the problem !